# yield in Ruby on Rails seems to add extra space when rendering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yield

I've got a problem with layouts and yield. When I follow the [guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#understanding-yield), I got extra space before the **p** tag. When I inspect the code with google chrome I got something like:

"
                    "

between the body and p tags. I type the same code as on the guide but it is not working, did I miss something?

Code for layout:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

and code for view:

```
<p>Hello, Rails!</p>
```

Comment: Code posted, as you can see, it is very simple.

Comment: what Rails version? I've just copypaste your example - and it works fine!

Comment: Rails 3.0.1 but I switched to 3.0.3 and still have the problem. When looking in source code, I found a '-' before the view output but don't know where it comes from.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I founded the problem. It was the UTF8 encoding. In Notepad++, You have to choose to encode in UTF8 but without 'BOM', if you choose only UTF8, you get that extra character which add space.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use minus sign:

```
<%= yield -%>
```

to prevent extra space after

Comment: Doesn't work, the extra space is before yield, if I have only plain text in the view in want to load within the layout, I don't have space but if I add p tags for example, I got extra space again :/